# Can I install Ubuntu 12.04 on MacBook 6.1 (Late 2009) on my external hard drive?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, macbook, external-hdd, refit

I have no experience in installing Linux based OS on MacBook, but I already have Windows installed on my Mac. I read some articles saying I can have the Lucid Lynx installed in my Macbook 6.1 and luckily I already got the CD (which was distributed for free back then haha), my question is that can I have the 12.04 installed instead of the 10.04 and what do I need to do that? I also would like to know can I install it on my external hard drive just like installing it on a usb stick? I have viewed the how-to for installing the Lucid Lynx, is it just the same? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. You want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on your hard-drive or using your hard drive?

Comment: well i want to install ubuntu on my external hard drive

Answer (score 3):

To install Ubuntu n your external hard-drive live boot from your Ubuntu CD/USB. When Ubuntu boots up click on install and select the following option during the installation:

[image]

If your computer has only 1 hard-disk, then your external hard-disk will appear as sdaB  Select your external hard-drive and partition and configure it as desired.

Continue installation as usual and Ubuntu will install on the USB Hard Drive.

Comment: thanks a lot! But what do you think about the compability issue

Comment: I think your computer should be compatible with Ubuntu.